# Getting the nth element using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

From a large table I want to read rows 5, 10, 15, 20 ... using BeautifulSoup. How do I do this? Is findNextSibling and an incrementing counter the way to go?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You could also use `findAll` to get all the rows in a list and after that just use the slice syntax to access the elements that you need:

```
rows = soup.findAll('tr')[4::5]
```

Comment: This is clean. Notice the find all method returns an array, so this is great.

Comment: how come slice works and single index doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

This can be easily done with `select` in beautiful soup if you know the row numbers to be selected. (Note : This is in bs4)

```
row = 5
while true
    element = soup.select('tr:nth-of-type('+ row +')')
    if len(element) > 0:
        # element is your desired row element, do what you want with it 
        row += 5
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue to OP but while this seems cleaner, it is not letting me extract ANY data from 'element' and any findAll search is just resulting in the entire page

Answer (score 2):

As a general solution, you can convert the table to a nested list and iterate...

```
import BeautifulSoup

def listify(table):
  """Convert an html table to a nested list""" 
  result = []
  rows = table.findAll('tr')
  for row in rows:
    result.append([])
    cols = row.findAll('td')
    for col in cols:
      strings = [_string.encode('utf8') for _string in col.findAll(text=True)]
      text = ''.join(strings)
      result[-1].append(text)
  return result

if __name__=="__main__":
    """Build a small table with one column and ten rows, then parse into a list"""
    htstring = """<table> <tr> <td>foo1</td> </tr> <tr> <td>foo2</td> </tr> <tr> <td>foo3</td> </tr> <tr> <td>foo4</td> </tr> <tr> <td>foo5</td> </tr>  <tr> <td>foo6</td> </tr>  <tr> <td>foo7</td> </tr>  <tr> <td>foo8</td> </tr>  <tr> <td>foo9</td> </tr>  <tr> <td>foo10</td> </tr></table>"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(htstring)
    for idx, ii in enumerate(listify(soup)):
        if ((idx+1)%5>0):
            continue
        print ii
```

Running that...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ python testme.py
['foo5']
['foo10']
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you prefer raw html...

```
"""Build a small table with one column and ten rows, then parse it into a list"""
htstring = """<table> <tr> <td>foo1</td> </tr> <tr> <td>foo2</td> </tr> <tr> <td>foo3</td> </tr> <tr> <td>foo4</td> </tr> <tr> <td>foo5</td> </tr>  <tr> <td>foo6</td> </tr>  <tr> <td>foo7</td> </tr>  <tr> <td>foo8</td> </tr>  <tr> <td>foo9</td> </tr>  <tr> <td>foo10</td> </tr></table>"""
result = [html_tr for idx, html_tr in enumerate(soup.findAll('tr')) \
     if (idx+1)%5==0]
print result
```

Running that...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ python testme.py
[<tr> <td>foo5</td> </tr>, <tr> <td>foo10</td> </tr>]
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could scrape every 5th distribution link on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) Wikipedia page with [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions"
soup = Soup.get(url)

a_tags = soup.find("a", {"href": "distribution"})
links = ["https://en.wikipedia.org" + a.attrs["href"] for a in a_tags]

links[4::5] # start at 0,1,2,3,**4** and stride by 5
```