# Fetching nth child using BeautifulSoup Python3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am using Python3 Beautiful Soup to scrap a website. This is the XML data I am getting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <title type="text">MATERIALSET('R100100100')</title>
        <updated>2018-05-11T04:28:47Z</updated>
        <category term="ZPOC_BOT_PUR_GRP_SRV.MATERIAL" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
        <link href="MATERIALSET('R100100100')" rel="self" title="MATERIAL"/>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:MATNR>R100100100</d:MATNR>
                <d:WERKS>Z100</d:WERKS>
                <d:MENGE>       1.000</d:MENGE>
                <d:EEIND>29.06.2018</d:EEIND>
                <d:BANFN>5000000041</d:BANFN>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
```

I just want to extract the data in d:BANFN. If I directly write soup.select('d:BANFN") it shows an error of 'nth_child_of_type'. I did go through some of the questions in Stackoverflow here are the links -
[Getting the nth element using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724352/getting-the-nth-element-using-beautifulsoup)
and
[selecting second child in beautiful soup with soup.select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720442/selecting-second-child-in-beautiful-soup-with-soup-select)
But nothing helps. 
Please help.

Comment: Where is  entry tag started?

Comment: I had to delete some of the tags for privacy and security purposes. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xml file there should be the starting tag for `entry` attribute then only you will be able to parse xml file:

```
<!-- Sample.xml contains following data: -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <entry>
        <title type="text">MATERIALSET('R100100100')</title>
        <updated>2018-05-11T04:28:47Z</updated>
        <category term="ZPOC_BOT_PUR_GRP_SRV.MATERIAL" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
        <link href="MATERIALSET('R100100100')" rel="self" title="MATERIAL"/>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:MATNR>R100100100</d:MATNR>
                <d:WERKS>Z100</d:WERKS>
                <d:MENGE>       1.000</d:MENGE>
                <d:EEIND>29.06.2018</d:EEIND>
                <d:BANFN>5000000041</d:BANFN>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("sample.xml", "r") as f: # opening xml file
    content = f.read() # xml content stored in this variable and decode to utf-8

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml') #parse content to BeautifulSoup Module

print("BANFN value : {}".format([ item.text for item in soup.find_all("d:banfn")][0])) #required result
```

---

```
#output:
BANFN value : 5000000041
```

Comment: Working. Thanks

Comment: @SarthakMahapatra Anytime:)